# Problem with toggling

Tags: textarea, toggle, fade

I have searched this forum but i can't get any solutions to work, im trying to toggle a textarea visibility but all textareas are being toggled at once. im fairly new with jquery but here is my code

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".note").hide();


  jQuery(".note_button").click(function() {
  jQuery(".note").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
  });
});

to work with this html:

```
<table>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' class='product-name'>
            </td>
                <td>

             </td>
    <td></td>
       <td class="cart-widget-remove">   

             </td>


      </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <form id="desc" action="" method="post" class="adjustform">
             <div class="note">
                <textarea name="" onfocus="this.value='';">Your optional note to the kitchen</textarea>
                <input class="" type="button" value="Apply changes" />
                <input class="" type="button" value="Cancel" />

             </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this pattern shows up multiple times on your page

```
<form id="desc" action="" method="post" class="adjustform">
  <div class="note">
    <textarea name="" onfocus="this.value='';">Your optional note to the kitchen</textarea>
    <input class="" type="button" value="Apply changes" />
    <input class="" type="button" value="Cancel" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Then your selector `jQuery('.note')` will select all .note divs. You'll need to give them unique IDs to select individual divs for hiding/showing or use the id already on the form.

```
jQuery('#desc .note').fadeToggle(...);
```

Comment: Yes thanks it seems my problem also gets alot more complex, as products are being added to the cart dynamically a unique id also has to be created which is where i am struggling a bit with now. Do you have any advice on how i could approach this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we only have part of the code, but I'll give it a shot...

The jQuery is toggling all areas because your selector isn't targeting the one you want to toggle specifically. Presumably you have other textareas that also are inside divs with the class "note". If each one of these divs had a unique class (say "note-1", "note-2", etc.) then you could select the specific textarea you wanted to toggle.

Comment: The problem is these products are being added dynamically, it would mean creating more JavaScript code on the fly also. Your idea works great if the products were available on the page once loaded.

Comment: My "idea" is actually not related to whether the content is added dynamically or not. Here is the point: to target a specific textarea, you need a selector that targets that textarea specifically. Your current code doesn't have that, which is why you see all textareas toggling. This is the problem you need to solve in order to use your javascript to do the toggle.